# Python Selenium - how to get text in div after span

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have a list of urls that go to different anime on myanimelist.net. For each anime, I want to get the text for the genres for each anime that can be found on the website and add it to a list of strings (one element for each anime, not 5 separate elements if an anime has 5 genres listed)

Here is the [HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBSx1.png) for an anime on myanimelist.net. I want to essentially get the genre text at top of the image and put in a list so in the image shown, its entry in the list would be `["Mystery, Police, Psychological, Supernatural, Thriller, Shounen"]` and for each url in my list, another string containing the genres for that anime is appended to the list.

This is the main part of my code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
flist = [url1, url2, url3]   #List of urls
genres = []
for item in flist:
    driver.get(item)   #Opens each url
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[16]").text
    genres.append(elem)
```

The code works for some anime and not for others. Sometimes the position is different for some anime and instead of getting the info about the genres, I get info about the studio that produced the anime, etc.

What I want is to specify "Genres:" in the span class and get the genres that are listed below it as shown in my image above. I can't seem to find anything similar to what I'm looking for (though I might just not be phrasing my questions right as well as a lack of experience using xpaths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get('https://myanimelist.net/anime/35760/Shingeki_no_Kyojin_Season_3')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(string(), 'Genres')]/a[contains(@href,'genre')]")
for link in links:
    title= elem.get_attribute("title")
    genres.append(title)
print(genres)
genresString = ",".join(genres)
print(genresString)
```

Sample Output:

```
['Action', 'Military', 'Mystery', 'Super Power', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Shounen']

Action,Military,Mystery,Super Power,Drama,Fantasy,Shounen
```

Comment: This works perfectly but is there any way to convert that list of strings into a single string list entry? I have a list of urls I am passing into the driver.get() statement so I want a single string entry of genres for each url so that the elements of both lists are the same number so instead of `['Action', 'Military', 'Mystery', 'Super Power', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Shounen']` it becomes `["Mystery, Police, Psychological, Supernatural, Thriller, Shounen"]`